# WPF scrollbar for a resizable window

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scroll, scrollviewer

This should be a very simple task, but for some reason I'm running into a lot of problems with it in WPF.

This is what I want to happen:
I have a bunch of controls in a window, including expander controls. I want to have scroll bars for that window, when content expands below the visible area. Also, the window is not of fixed width, it can be maximized, resized, etc.

I tried putting a ScrollViewer as the first element in the window, but it's not working correctly. If I set the height and width to Auto, it doesn't scroll and if i set it to spefic detentions, it creates a box when the window is maximized.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please explain, what does "it creates a box" mean? I didn't quite understand it.

Comment: Meaning that there is a fixed width area in the middle when the window around it expands

Comment: In this case, would you please post your XAML? Interesting is the Window itself and its immediate child element (ScrollViewer?).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have some fixed width issues.  If you provide a sample of your XAML I can see if I can help further.  The following works without showing a box:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSample1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel>
            <Rectangle Height="400" Width="400" Fill="Red" Margin="10" />
            <Rectangle Height="400" Width="400" Fill="Green" Margin="10" />
            <Rectangle Height="400" Width="400" Fill="Blue" Margin="10" />
            <Rectangle Height="400" Width="400" Fill="Yellow" Margin="10" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: Turns out it was fixed width issues with the cotnrols, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You should set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and the VerticalScrollBarVisibility of the ScrollViewer to Auto.

Here is an example:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Canvas Width="400" Height="400">
            <Button Canvas.Left="300">Left 300</Button>
            <Button Canvas.Top="300">Top 300</Button>
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

This replaces the content of the main window generated by VS.

Run it and change the size of the window, maximize it and you'll scroll bars appearing and disappearing.